# Disable possibility of saving 2 Children to Parent in OneToOne association

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

It is possible to save same parent to 2 children:

[image]

[image]

I want to disable this possibility.

the domains:

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToOne
    Parent parent;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="parent")
    private Child child;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @PreRemove
    private void preRemove() {
        child.setParent(null);
    }

}
```

How to change this code to disable possiblity of having same parent for 2 children? Should I craete FK or somethin? How do that in elegant way with JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `@JoinColumn` on your `@OneToOne` and add `unique = true`. This way uniqness of parents will be checked at the database side:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", unique = true)
Parent parent;
```